# How to install spree on my mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, spree

I have been trying to install spree on my machine for the past 5 days, and I just find it IMPOSSIBLE.

It seems like whatever I try to do theres always an issue with compatibility, whether is gem compatibility on spree compatibility. So I am wondering if anyone has a guide on how to install it?

I am currently using rails(4.0.0) and I know it is not compatible  with spree, but I have no idea how to downgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

Though this seems not exactly what you ask for, but the easiest way to downgrade your rails gem is:

```
gem uninstall rails
gem install rails -v 3.2.13

# then you can install spree
gem install spree
rails _3.2.13_ new my_store
spree install my_store
```